# plotting multiple histograms using different line styles python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to plot multiple histograms using different line styles as I cannot use color to distinguish them. I get it but still, these look very similar as two plots have very similar distribution. Can I get different markers such as dots, stars etc or some better way to distinguish these?
This is what I have

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('PS')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.hist(values1, histtype='step', linestyle=':',label=topic1)
plt.hist(values2, histtype='step', linestyle='--',color=color, label=topic2)
plt.hist(values3,histtype='step', linestyle='solid', label=topic3)

plt.legend(loc="upper right")
plt.legend(frameon=False)
plt.show()
plt.savefig(allplotfile)
plt.close()
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use **hatching**, e.g. `hatch="\\\\"` in the call to `hist`. I'm not convinced that it looks better, but it's at least an option.

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use("grayscale")
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(1)
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (4,3)

vals = np.arange(2,5.1,0.5)
p = np.array([1,.2,.36,.15,.38,.28,.4])
p = p/np.sum(p)
a = np.random.choice(vals, size=100, p=p)
b = np.random.choice(vals, size=100, p=p)
c = np.random.choice(vals, size=100, p=p)


plt.hist(a, histtype='step', linestyle=':',label="topic1", hatch="\\\\")
plt.hist(b, histtype='step', linestyle='--', label="topic2", hatch="//")
plt.hist(c,histtype='step', linestyle='solid', label="topic3", hatch="++")

plt.legend(loc="upper right")
plt.legend(frameon=False)
plt.show()
```

Different **linewidths** may also help: `lw=2` etc,
(here I used `1`, `2` and `3` as linewidths)

[image]

Different **shades of gray**, combines with **alpha** settings may also help:

```
plt.hist(a, linestyle=':',  color=plt.cm.gray(0.1), alpha=0.5)
plt.hist(b, linestyle='--' ,color=plt.cm.gray(0.4), alpha=0.5)
plt.hist(c, linestyle='solid', color=plt.cm.gray(0.8), alpha=0.5)
```

[image]